# FET - confirm if both circuits are equivalent for medium frequencies

Tags: circuit-analysis, fet

I would like to make an incremental model of the transistor for medium frequencies. I've tried to make the matrix. Could you confirm if the two circuits are equivalent for medium frequencies, please?
[image][image]

---

New circuit:
[image]

Comment: @TonyStewart.EEsince'75 Can you tell me if the circuits are equivalent for medium frequencies, please? Is the circuit with hybrid parameters well done?

Comment: No - they are not equivalent - look at what you have for R1, R2 and R3.

Comment: @KevinWhite How can I do to give correct? This is the first time I do this. I have only learned by watching videos and examples, on my own. Could you please help me?

Comment: You are on the right track but for example does the input signal have to go through R3 to get to the gate?

Comment: i.e .is Vg connected to R3 ? or R1//R2 as you showed.

Comment: @KevinWhite No, the input signal does not have to go through R3 to reach the gate. So I have to remove R3 from the drawing, right?
Another question: from what I realized, I have to remove R3 from the drawing because the input signal does not have to go through R3 to get to the gate. But why do not I also remove R1 and R2? The input signal does not have to go through R1 and R2 to get to the gate, right?

Comment: @CarmenGonzález - Correct, the signal does not go through the R1,R2,R3 network but the signal does get to them so they have to be represented in the small signal equivalent circuit.

Comment: @KevinWhite Sorry, i don't understand. Which of the three resistences has to be represented? And why? What is the correct circuit? Thanks for help

Comment: R3 should appear in series with the parallel combination of R1 and R2 to ground.

Comment: @KevinWhite But in my drawing R3 is in parallel with R1 and R2. What is wrong in my drawing?

Comment: R3 is not in parallel with R1/R2. R1 and R2 should be in parallel. R3 is in series with that combination.  That network is then in parallel with the gate.

Comment: @KevinWhite I've already made the circuit. I put it in the post. I am now in great doubt. How can I know the lower cut-off frequency of the amplifier? I've looked everywhere, I've been trying for two days, but I do not know how. Thanks.

Comment: First put the capacitors into your equivalent circuit - then you will be able to see the places that will result in low frequency roll-off.  Don't forget to add the output capacitor and the input impedance  of the load.

Comment: You will need to add r5 and c2 to your circuit as well.

Comment: @KevinWhite I do not understand. The statement also says that I have to add a load resistor (1k) at the output. I've been seeing resolutions on the internet that say that the coupling capacitors are replaced by short circuits. The coupling capacitors are C1 and C3. But then what do I do? Do I have to use the incremental scheme? Could you be a little clearer, please? I'm a beginner.

Comment: You have to add the capacitors if you want to determine the lower cutoff frequency.  The rest of the circuit will work down to DC.

Comment: @KevinWhite But do I have to add all the capacitors to the incremental scheme or the original circuit?